# Upper bound of convergence of ellipsoid mathod

Tags: calculus, optimization, linear-programming

Actually, I am looking for a tighter upper bound for $(1+\frac{1}{n^2 - 1})^{n-1} (\frac{n}{n+1})^{2}$. It is easy to prove $(1+\frac{1}{n^2 - 1})^{n-1} (\frac{n}{n+1})^2 < e^{-\frac{1}{n+1}}$.

But I found that in some papers, $(1+\frac{1}{n^2 - 1})^{n-1} (\frac{n}{n+1})^2$ can be bounded by $e^{-\frac{1}{n}}$.

So I just want to know that how to get this bound?

Comment: Good question. Could you show how the $e^{-\frac1{n+1}}$ bound is derived?

Comment: Actually, you can prove by using $\lim_{n\to \infty }(1 + \frac{1}{n})^n = e$ and $1+x \leq e^x$. By using calculus, we can prove the upper bound $e^{-\frac{1}{n}}$

Comment: I do not see this. Since you have answered your question, can you type up your solution as as a solution and accept it? That would help me to understand and is also proper etiquette in this situation.